# Take the string from an listView with a contextmenuinfo

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

I have a project from an Android application and I want that when I click on an option in a contextMenu I see the String of that position.

```
String[] datos = {"Victor","Silvia","Manolo","Carlos","Ana"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> adaptador = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, datos);

    milista.setAdapter(adaptador);
```

And this is the method to do something by click an intem of the context menu

```
 @Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.action_mostrar:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),info.position+": Opción mostrar" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        case R.id.action_eliminar:
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), info.position+": Opción eliminar", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;

        default:
            return false;

    }
}
```

How should I do it?

**Edit:**

the problem is solved, I leave the code solved:

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        String selectedWord = ((TextView) info.targetView).getText().toString();
        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.action_mostrar:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),selectedWord+": Opción mostrar" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_eliminar:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedWord+": Opción eliminar" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;

        }
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: you are setting values for spinner right ? than *setOnItemSelectedListener* will work

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the position to retrieve the string from your string array like this

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()){

            case R.id.action_mostrar:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),datos[info.position]+": Opción mostrar" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            case R.id.action_eliminar:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), datos[info.position]+": Opción eliminar" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return true;

            default:
                return false;

        }
    }
```